# Is there a way to view wireshark .pcap files in Fiddler?

Tags: fiddler, wireshark

Is there a way to convert [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) .pcap files to a format that [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) understands?

Every so often we get network traces generated from wireshark in .pcap files.  Most of the time the traces contain mostly HTTP traffic which I find much easier to analyze using fiddler.

Comment: Note: Do you know that you can enter "http" and click apply in wireshark to filter for http requests and responses?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that.  I find the fiddler UI is better suited to analyze http traffic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fiddler 2 and Fiddler 4 now include import support for PCAP, PCAPNG, and NetMon files. Click File > Import > Packet Capture.

Note that only HTTP traffic will be imported (HTTPS traffic is encrypted, and FTP traffic wasn't a priority).

Comment: Are you open sourcing this?  I've been playing with pcap.net in an attempt to write a importer but if you're working on it already I wouldn't mind getting involved in some form

Comment: What's the status of this importer?

Comment: Does the "Fiddler 4 supports pcap files" answer indicate that the importer is part of Fiddler 4?  And does it also support pcap-ng files?  (If so, please make sure it doesn't assume all Interface Description Blocks are at the beginning of a file....)

Comment: @GuyHarris: Fiddler2 and Fiddler4 both now import PCAP, PCAPNG, and NetMon CAP files. If you have a problem with any file, please click Help > Send Feedback.

Comment: OK, I tested Fiddler2 with a file that has two IDBs, one of which appears late in the capture, followed by packets for the second interface; it looked as if it was handled correctly.  That *probably* means Fiddler2 (and Fiddler4, if the code paths are the same and the only differences are .Net 2 vs. .Net 4 differences) will handle pcap-ng files that don't have all the IDBs at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ColaSoft Packet Player](http://www.colasoft.com/packet_player/) which enables to play captured .pcap files and open fiddler on capturing all processes and receive all data as it was captured.

Comment: Nice!  I'm going to have to try this out.  Thanks for the post

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler 4 supports pcap files.

Comment: Don't you think this looks like a comment!

Comment: No, it looks like an answer, i.e. a way to view pcap files in Fiddler is to get Fiddler 4 and read them in.  (This is presumably the result of @EricLaw's work on the importer mentioned in his answer.)